# Override method within abstract class

Tags: c#, overriding, abstract-class, abstract

I am currently reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3z1377.aspx) from MSDN (which is also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)). As a newbie, I can't figure out why there is an `override` method within an abstract class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Id + " Area = " + string.Format("{0:F2}",Area);
}
```

I thought `override` is used to provide/override implementation after extending from an abstract or virtual class, but I don't understand why there's an `override` method ***within*** an abstract class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All classes derived from class `System.Object` (*ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework*).

Class `Shape` in the example is overriding `ToString()` method from class [System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx).